# SpriteFont rendering artefacts

Tags: monogame

I'm attempting to render a SpriteFont in MonoGame using the following code:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(hudFont, "HP: " + p.Attributes.Hp + " / " + p.Attributes.MaxHp, EDGE_BUFFER, Color.White);
```

Where hudFont is loaded as a regular SpriteFont via the content manager. When I render the text on-screen, it looks like this:

[image: Artefacts]

I've never encountered this issue before and am at a loss for what might be causing it. Anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I solved the problem by changing the **TextureFormat** setting of the SpriteFont to **NoChange** from within the MonoGame Pipeline tool.

Not sure what the problem was; I've never run into that issue with the default settings before!